# How to move back and forth after firing a gun

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics

I'm having a problem with my code in unity: (I don't have any animations)

```
public GameObject gun;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(moveobject());
    }
}
IEnumerator moveobject()
{
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        gun.transform.position += new Vector3(1,0,0);
        yield return 0;
    }

    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        gun.transform.position += new Vector3(-1,0,0);
        yield return 0;

    }
}
```

When I shoot (without turning) it does go back and forth, but when I turn to left or right, my gun goes somewhere.

Is there any other code that moves back and forth? It's like a realistic gun animation but through scripting

Comment: you need to explain your question more. move what? where is the code that moves what around?

Comment: i thought u understand my code,,, the `gameobject`called `gun`  moves because of vector3.

Comment: ok. where is the code that moves what around?

Comment: may bad. you said when you turn left or right around, it goes somewhere. do you mind posting the turn code and also, where is that somewhere?

Comment: o.O? uhhhhhmm.. what?

Answer (score 0):

try this, if Z axis is your forward direction:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    gun.transform.position += gun.transform.forward;
    yield return 0;
}

for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    gun.transform.position -= gun.transform.forward;
    yield return 0;
}
```

this will move the gun in the forward direction of the gun

if you turn, the forward direction is not (0,0,1)

you can also use this if X axis is your forward direction:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    gun.transform.position += gun.transform.right;
    yield return 0;
}

for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    gun.transform.position -= gun.transform.right;
    yield return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is to consider your object rotation before telling it to move. When you update an objects position towards `Vector3(1,0,0)` you have to remember that this vector is moving the object in global coordinates, and since your object rotated its X axis is no longer the same as the world axis.

To transform move this new vector to your objects orientation you have to multiply it by the objects rotation matrix. Your code would be something like:

```
IEnumerator moveobject()
{
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        gun.transform.position += gun.transform.rotation * Vector3.right;
        yield return 0;
    }

    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        gun.transform.position += gun.transform.rotation * Vector3.left;
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```